# Android 2.1 link a string

Tags: android

does anybody know how to make a link accessible? For example, if I receive a message that includes www.stackoverflow.com in my application, the user to be able to access the link? The message comes on a web view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a `TextView` and use `linkify` feature

check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) out